# JSF - How to process data in a Bean after being redirected to JSF view from Servlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

Basically, I have a view in which the user will enter some information and Submit it. This information will be sent to a Third Party that will process the data. The third party will post the result back to me, and I will intercept it in a Servlet. Now, in order to move on in my application, depending on the result that has been sent back to me by the Third Party, I need to verify the value that my Servlet received in one of my Session Beans (The reason I cannot verify that value directly in the Servlet is that I need some information from my Beans), so my question is, how can I do that without being able to access the FacesContext from the Servlet?

I understand that I could precreate the FacesContext directly in my Servlet in order to access it but I also understand that this is not recommended. I have also heard about using a PhaseListener, but I have no idea how to achieve this in my case and I am unsure if that would really solve my problem and if there is not an easier solution.

This is what I have right now:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
ServletException, IOException
{
    try
    {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String response = req.getParameter( "response");
        HttpSession sess = req.getSession();

        MyBean myBean= (MyBean) sess.getAttribute("myBean");

        //I am setting the response in my bean here, so I can 
        //use it later to verify its value and move on the user within 
        //the application depending of the value
        myBean.setResponse(response);

        resp.sendRedirect("view1.jsf");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

This actually works, and I am being redirected to view1, however, I don't know how to call the Bean which I want to verify the response from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here. (If I am lucky I might get some insights from @BalusC ;) )

Comment: If this is a JSF managed bean, can't you call it using #{myBean} on the view?

Comment: @Nikhil Talreja Absolutely yes. It is a JSF managed bean and I could use #{myBean}. But my goal is to verify the response received by the Servlet immediately after receiving it, without requiring any action by the user.

Comment: What kind of bean you are trying to call , from which portion of your code xhtml , servlet ?

Comment: Do you need to call a method on the JSF bean, *inside* the servlet?

Comment: As long as I can pass the value that the Servlet received back in my JSF context in order to use it in my Beans, I can call my verification method in the Bean either from the servlet or not. Basically what I am trying to achieve here is a 2 factor authentication. Once the user logs in with his credentials, a third party will interact with the user and then post back the result of that interaction to the servlet. Depending on the result, I need to either log the user in or send him back to authentication step 1. So basically I just need to pass the value back to the servlet and finish the job.

Comment: @kolossus - Thanks for taking some time to help me, I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: You could easily just pass the necessary parameter back to the JSF view and pick it up in the bean: `resp.sendRedirect("view1.jsf?param=someParam");`

Comment: @Avinash Singh - The Bean that will be called to verify the response is a Request Bean. This bean will use a Session Bean that already have data as a result of step #1.

Comment: @kolossus - Could you please give me a short example of how to pick up the param in the URL from my view and pass it back to my Bean? How would I then be able to verify the param value in my bean without requiring any action from the user once the view picks up the value from the URL?

Comment: @kolossus - After researching your last advice, I think I should have mentioned that I am using JSF 1.1, as I think you might have been thinking of using <f:viewParam> in the view in order to set the value in the Bean. But then, I still don't get how I could verify the data in the bean immediately after the servlet redirect, without requiring any user action.

Comment: `<f:viewParam>` is not available in v1.x as you already know. You can get parameters off the URL with `FacesContext#ExternalContext#getRequest()`. You can try to grab the parameters in the constructor of your backing bean (there's no support for `@PostConstruct` in v1.x)